# PHPExcel: No default style found for this workbook

Tags: php, phpexcel, import-from-excel

I'm trying to convert xlsx to pdf with PHPExcel+DOMPdf and get this exception: 
"No default style found for this workbook".

Here's some stack trace:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/clients/client46/web339/web/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 365

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/clients/client46/web339/web/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 402

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/clients/client46/web339/web/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 1715

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'No default style found for this workbook' in /var/www/clients/client46/web339/web/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php:930 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/clients/client46/web339/web/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/HTML.php(142): PHPExcel->getDefaultStyle() #1
```

I've also tried tcpdf, but I keep getting this error as well.

Comment: How was the xlsx file generated? Was it from MS Excel itself, or from some other application?

Comment: @MarkBaker there was a template from msexcel, in which formulas were calculated and turned into static values with phpexcel, then unwanted sheets were removed.